# How can I write this jQuery code different and more simple?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My HTML:

```
    <div class="text-left pb-5">
        <h6>Aantal</h6>
        <input type="text" class="calc" id="aantal" name="aantal" value="100" style="padding-left: 5px">
    </div>

    <div class="text-left pb-5">
        <h6>Kleur</h6>
        <input type="text" class="calc" id="kleur" name="kleur" value="5" style="padding-left: 5px">
    </div>

    <div class="text-left pb-5">
        <h6>Grootte</h6>
        <input type="text" class="calc" id="grootte" name="grootte" value="50" style="padding-left: 5px">
    </div>

    <div class="text-left pt-5">
        <h6>Prijs</h6>
        <input type="text" id="prijs" name="prijs" readonly style="padding-left: 5px">
    </div>
```

My jQuery code:

```
    $(".calc").on('change keydown paste input', function(){
    if($('#grootte').val() <= 50 && $('#aantal').val() <= 25 && $('#kleur').val() == 1) {
        $("#prijs").val('7.35');
    }
    else if($('#grootte').val() <= 50 && $('#aantal').val() <= 25 && $('#kleur').val() == 2) {
        $("#prijs").val('8.60');
    }
    else if($('#grootte').val() <= 50 && $('#aantal').val() <= 25 && $('#kleur').val() == 3) {
        $("#prijs").val('10.30');
    }
    else if($('#grootte').val() <= 50 && $('#aantal').val() <= 25 && $('#kleur').val() == 4) {
        $("#prijs").val('12.40');
    }
    else if($('#grootte').val() <= 50 && $('#aantal').val() <= 25 && $('#kleur').val() == 5) {
        $("#prijs").val('14.80');
    }
    else if($('#grootte').val() <= 50 && $('#aantal').val() <= 25 && $('#kleur').val() == 6) {
        $("#prijs").val('17.80');
    }
    else if($('#grootte').val() <= 50 && $('#aantal').val() <= 25 && $('#kleur').val() == 7) {
        $("#prijs").val('14.85');
    }
});

    $(".calc").on('change keydown paste input', function(){
        if($('#grootte').val() >= 50 && $('#grootte').val() <= 150 && $('#aantal').val() <= 25 && $('#kleur').val() == 1) {
            $("#prijs").val('7.95');
        }
        else if($('#grootte').val() >= 50 && $('#grootte').val() <= 150 && $('#aantal').val() <= 25 && $('#kleur').val() == 2) {
            $("#prijs").val('8.60');
        }
        else if($('#grootte').val() >= 50 && $('#grootte').val() <= 150 && $('#aantal').val() <= 25 && $('#kleur').val() == 3) {
            $("#prijs").val('10.30');
        }
        else if($('#grootte').val() >= 50 && $('#grootte').val() <= 150 && $('#aantal').val() <= 25 && $('#kleur').val() == 4) {
            $("#prijs").val('12.40');
        }
        else if($('#grootte').val() >= 50 && $('#grootte').val() <= 150 && $('#aantal').val() <= 25 && $('#kleur').val() == 5) {
            $("#prijs").val('14.80');
        }
        else if($('#grootte').val() >= 50 && $('#grootte').val() <= 150 && $('#aantal').val() <= 25 && $('#kleur').val() == 6) {
            $("#prijs").val('17.80');
        }
        else if($('#grootte').val() >= 50 && $('#grootte').val() <= 150 && $('#aantal').val() <= 25 && $('#kleur').val() == 7) {
            $("#prijs").val('14.85');
        }
    });
```

This jQuery code is very repetitive and I would like to simplify it, but I am not really sure how I could do this. Could anyone help me out? This is only part of the jQuery code, all the inputs will have different values and outcomes.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! What task does this code accomplish? Please tell us, and also make that the title of the question via [edit]. Maybe you missed the placeholder on the title element: "_State the task that your code accomplishes. Make your title distinctive._". Also from  [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to approach this kind of thing is to look for commonalities in your code. So taking just a part of the first handler my first step would be:

```
 $(".calc").on('change keydown paste input', function() {
    bar kleur    = $('#kleur').val(); 
    var in_range = $('#grootte').val() <= 50 && $('#aantal').val() <= 25;
    var result;
    if (in_range && kleur == 1) {
        result = '7.35';
    } else if (in_range && kleur == 2 {       
        result = '8.60';
    }
    $("#prijs").val(result);
 });
```

The next step is to take out the common if condition:

```
 $(".calc").on('change keydown paste input', function() {
    var kleur    = $('#kleur').val(); 
    var in_range = $('#grootte').val() <= 50 && $('#aantal').val() <= 25;
    var result;
    if (in_range) {
      if (kleur == 1) {
        result = '7.35';
      } else if (kleur == 2 {       
        result = '8.60';
      }
    }
    if (result)
      $("#prijs").val(result);
 });
```

I could also have used a case statement there but I'm going to use a lookup table instead:

```
 var result_lookup = {
    1: '7.35',
    2: '8.60',
 }

 $(".calc").on('change keydown paste input', function() {
    var kleur    = $('#kleur').val(),
        groote   = $('#grootte').val(),
        aantal   = $('#aantal').val();
    var in_range = groote <= 50 && aantal <= 25;
    var result;
    if (in_range) {
        result = result_lookup[kleur];
    }
    if (result)
       $("#prijs").val(result);
 });
```

And now to combine both handlers in a single handler:

```
 var result_lookup_1 = {
    1: '7.35',
    2: '8.60',
 }
 var result_lookup_2 = {
    1: '7.95',
    2: '8.60',
 }

 $(".calc").on('change keydown paste input', function() {
    var kleur    = $('#kleur').val(),
        groote   = $('#grootte').val(),
        aantal   = $('#aantal').val();
    var result;
    if ( groote <= 50 && aantal <= 25 ) {
        result = result_lookup_1[kleur];
    } else if (groote >= 50 && groote <= 150 && aantal <= 25 {
        result = result_lookup_2[kleur];
    }
    if (result)
       $("#prijs").val(result);
 });
```

Comment: Wow that is a very detailed answer, thanks a lot for that! Explaining it step by step really helped me understand the solution, thank you!